# PHP MySQLi while loop logic

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have switched over to the `mysqli_` extension for PHP, and I have ran into a bit of an issue.

I have 2 databases. 1 database I am only allowed read privileges, the other I have all privileges. My end goal is to read what I need from database 1, and put it in a table in database 2.

I use a join on database 1 to get all the information I need. I then loop through the results with a while loop. I have a unique id (`domainid`) in both databases. Where I am encountering the issue is inside the while loop once I have the `domainid` from the read-only database, I need to check if it exists inside my all-privileges database. I am just unsure of how to accomplish this?

Here is the code:

```
require 'db/connect.php';
require 'db/connect2.php';

if($result = $db->query("
    SELECT  tblhosting.domain as domain, tblhosting.id as domainid, tblclients.email as email
    FROM tblhosting
    LEFT JOIN tblclients ON
    tblclients.id = tblhosting.userid
    ")){
    if ($count = $result->num_rows) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $domainid = $row->domainid;
            $domain = $row->domain;
            $email = $row->email;

            $result2 = $db2->prepare("SELECT domainid FROM information WHERE domainid = ?");
            $result2->bind_param('i', $row->domainid);
            $result2->execute();
            $result2->bind_result($domainid2);
            //$result2->fetch();

            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_object()){                
            $domainid2 = $row2->domainid;
            if ($domainid == $domainid2) {
                echo "Information exists in both Databases", '<br>';
            }

            else{
                echo "New Information Added to Database 2", '<br>';

            }
        }
        }
    }   
}
```

This is what I have tried, but was unsuccessful.

**EDIT**

Second attempt putting the results into an array then looping through them. The array is correct when I print them out. The issue is with the 2nd execute(); command.

```
$result = $db->query("
        SELECT  tblhosting.domain as domain, tblhosting.id as domainid, tblclients.email as email
        FROM tblhosting
        LEFT JOIN tblclients ON
        tblclients.id = tblhosting.userid
        ");

        $domainid_arr = array();    
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $domainid_arr[] = array(
                'domainid' => $row->domainid,
                'domain' => $row->domain
            );  
        }

        foreach ($domainid_arr as $d) {
            echo $d['domainid'], $d['domain'], '<br>';

            $result2 = $db2->prepare("SELECT domainid FROM information WHERE domainid = ?");
            $result2->bind_param('i', $d['domainid']);
            $result2->execute();
            $result2->bind_result($domainid2);

            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_object()){                
                $domainid2 = $row2->domainid;
                if ($d['domainid'] == $domainid2) {
                    echo "Information exists in both Databases", '<br>';
                }
                else{
                    echo "New Information Added to Database 2", '<br>';

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Was this erroring or just not doing what you wanted it to do

Comment: Hi Ruby. Sorry for the late reply. Nothing happens when I run this. However if I comment out the $result2 and the while loops, then echo $domainid, $domain, $email it prints out the correct information from the first query. But what I dont understand is why I can not use that information in my second while loop